# Python set usage, returning a union, tradeoffs for type flexibiltiy

Tags: python, types, set

I've been using sets quite a lot.

```
>>> s1
set(['a', 'b'])
```

Use of the methods allow for type conversion, while overloaded operators do not.

```
>>> s1.issubset('abc')
True
>>> s1 <= 'abc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only compare to a set
>>> s1 <= set('abc')
True
```

I want to be able to unite a set with a union to another set in a function:

```
>>> s1 | set('bc') # returns the union without modifying either
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])

>>> s1.union('bc') # allows for type conversion.
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

It seems my best options for a function that does this are:

```
def add_elements_strict(collector_set):
    do_stuff()
    return collector_set | more_elements()
```

or like this.

```
def add_elements_from_any_iterable(collector_set):
    do_stuff()
    return collector_set.union(more_elements())
```

Which would be the better choice? Clearly the first would give a `TypeError` if given anything but a set, but the second would give greater flexibility. My questions:

**Do I gain anything from ensuring I'm always passing this function a set?**

**Is the flexibility of being able to pass any iterable worth it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you *want* to be able to pass an arbitrary iterable? Are you *going* to pass anything other than a set? It's kind of tough to answer your question the way you've put it. The advantage of ensuring it's a set is you will get a loud warning if it isn't. Whether the flexibility is "worth it" depends on what else you're doing with the other things.  If the things you're going to be unioning are sets that you need to manipulate as sets in their own right, might as well leave them as sets.  If they're always going to be lists and/or tuples because you're using them as lists/tuples in other contexts, then maybe it makes sense to accept any iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set.update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) for an in-place update which returns an union

Quoting from the docs

> Update the set, adding elements from all others.

Example

```
>>> s1 = set('a')
>>> s1.update('ba')
>>> s1
set(['a', 'b'])
```